# Regarding deploying application across multiple jvm using ant script

Tags: java, jvm, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

This may sound like a dumb question. In my application, I have a scheduler which schedules the job and WEB UI where the user interacts and monitors the status of the job. There is a job processing mechanism which runs a thread every 5 minutes to check for the status of the thread. Currently everything is running under one JVM. I want to deploy scheduling part and web ui part in different jvms so that the web ui does not get bogged down when jobs are being scheduled and fired up in the backend.

My question is - *how can i deploy part of the application(WEB UI) in one JVM and another part of the application(scheduling and running of the job) in another jvm?*

Another question I have is regarding the architecture of the scheduling mechanism. My proposed architecture is we have a scheduler layer and a web ui interaction layer. From there we put jobs in the JMS Queue or ActiveMQ and then we have different java processes (different jvms running) that will pick the job from the ActiveMQ and process it and we have to make sure that state of jobs is being properly communicated between different jvms. Does this idea make sense? If so then would quartz be an appropriate tool here? What are the alternative solutions keeping my requirements in mind?

Thanks!

Comment: also how can i deploy scheduling mechanism using ant script onto a different jvm?

Comment: Is there an standard approach that I should be using for it or any other topics that I should be searching or exploring to get related information?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?? I must say my application mimics your application exactly and I want to do the same thing that you were trying to do and I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to want to keep the scheduler piece separate from the web ui. Assuming you have two different ear or war files, it should be relatively easy to perform. Setup another JVM, deploy only the ui ear/war file to it and you should be good to go.

Comment: can you elaborate on setting up another JVM part, am kind of new to this practice and so want to explore more?

Comment: Depending on the application server (JBoss, WebSphere, WebLogic) you will need to setup at least two instances. Allocate one instance to the ui and the second one to the scheduler piece. Deploy the war/ear files accordingly to each instance.